POST request(Login API) from the api gateway is not accepted and coming as 401 Unauthorized in java 17, spring 3.2.2
There are 3 microservices created in java 17, springboot 3.2.2.
The API gateway(running on port 3002), is given in the config.js file from frontend react application.
In API gateway, there is audit interceptor which has the prehandle method, which will call the service registry(port 3003) which is the application for eureka server.
There is login API in the eureka client application(running on port 3004) which is a post request and being called by the POST request.
The client application is registered in the eureka server. But the API gateway is not able to login. Please note that all the code was running in java 1.8 and I upgraded the system from java 1.8 to 17.
API gateway code(Audit interceptor):
@Component
@Configurable
public class AuditInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
//autowired code

@PostConstruct
    public void initilizeAuditInterceptor() {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (appProperty != null) {
                        List<AppPropery> appProperties = appProperty.findAll();
                        if (appProperties != null && appProperties.size() > 0) {
                            AppPropery propery = appProperties.get(0);
                            sessionExpireAt = propery.getSessionTimeout();
                        }
                    }
                    SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME = Duration.ofMinutes(Long.parseLong(sessionExpireAt)).toMillis();
                    expiryMap = ExpiringMap.builder().expirationPolicy(ExpirationPolicy.ACCESSED).expiration(Long.parseLong(sessionExpireAt), TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        
    }

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        try {
            //below is for preflight request
            if("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())){
                return true;
            }
            LOGGER.info("Api trigged: {}", request.getRequestURI());
            
            String jsessionId = request.getHeader("jsessionid");
            
            if (jsessionId == null) {
                if (request.getRequestURI().contains("login") || request.getRequestURI().contains("logout")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("updatedocusignstatus")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("avatar")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("export")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("studentPic")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("download")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("pdfs")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("docusignreport")||(request.getRequestURI().contains("forms")&&request.getRequestURI().contains("envelopes"))) {
                     persistAudit(request);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    response.setStatus(401);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (jsessionId.indexOf("JSESSIONID") > -1) {
                    jsessionId = jsessionId.substring(jsessionId.indexOf("JSESSIONID=") + 11);
                }
                if (request.getRequestURI().contains("login") || request.getRequestURI().contains("logout")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("avatar")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("export")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("studentPic")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("download")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("pdfs")
                        || request.getRequestURI().contains("docusignreport")
                        ||(request.getRequestURI().contains("forms")&&request.getRequestURI().contains("envelopes"))) {
                    persistAudit(request);
                    return true;
                } else if (!isSessionValid(jsessionId, request)) {
                    response.setStatus(401);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    persistAudit(request);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured in API Gateway interceptor while auditing == {}", ex);
        }
        return true;
    }


    private boolean isSessionValid(String jsessionId, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (expiryMap != null) {

            LoginStatus expiringLoginStatus = expiryMap.get(jsessionId);
            if (expiringLoginStatus != null) {
                Date dateUsed = expiringLoginStatus.getLastUsedTime() == null ? expiringLoginStatus.getLoginTime():expiringLoginStatus.getLastUsedTime();
                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - dateUsed.getTime()) > SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME) {
                    asyncExecutor.updateSessionLoginStatus(expiringLoginStatus);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    expiringLoginStatus.setLastUsedTime(new Date());
                    expiryMap.put(expiringLoginStatus.getSessionId(), expiringLoginStatus);
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                LoginStatus loginStatus = loginStatusRepository.getLoginStatusBySessionId(jsessionId);
                Date dateUsed = loginStatus.getLastUsedTime() == null ? loginStatus.getLoginTime():loginStatus.getLastUsedTime(); 
                if (loginStatus != null) {
                    if (loginStatus.isSessionExpired()) {
                        return false;
                    } else if(((loginStatus != null && !loginStatus.isSessionExpired()) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - dateUsed
                            .getTime()) > SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME)) {
                        asyncExecutor.updateSessionLoginStatus(loginStatus);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        loginStatus.setLastUsedTime(new Date());
                        expiryMap.put(loginStatus.getSessionId(), loginStatus);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

In the above code the expiry map is coming out as null
application.yml of api gateway.

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway

server:
  port: 3002

zuul:
  #Service will be mapped under the /api URI
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    email:
      path: /email/**
      serviceId: email
      #url: http://localhost:3004
    audit:
      path: /audit/**
  host:
      connect-timeout-millis: 60000 # starting the connection
      socket-timeout-millis: 60000  # monitor the continuous incoming data flow

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false

ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 120000
  ConnectTimeout: 120000


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:3003/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

logoutURL: http://localhost:3004/logout
loggedInSessionURL: http://localhost:3004/loggedInSession

This is the response I am receiving
Eureka Dashboard
Any help is appreciated...
I am expecting the login response to be 200 OK. And the application to be logged in.
